# D3 How can i replace a SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg like

```
<svg>
<g>
  <rect x='0' y='0' height='20' width='20' class='shape rect'/>
  <text x='10' y='10' text-anchor='middle' alignment-baseline='middle'>A</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

On user input I am trying to replace the shape `<rect>` to a different shape (say a circle)

In my JS I have:

```
// New User Data
var myData = [{
  text:A,
  shape:'circle',
  x:10,
  y:10
}];

// Remove existing shape and replace with a new shape
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var g = svg.select('g');
var sh = g.select('.shape);
sh.remove();
var newsh = g.selectAll('.shape').data(myData);
newsh.enter().append('circle').attr({
  cx: function(d){ return d.x;},
  cy: funciton(d){ return d.y;},
  r:10
})
.classed('shape circle',true);
```

This appends a new item to the group after the `<text>` element covering up the text.  How can I specify the position of the elements when building new data.

EDIT: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4jmnxdh0/6/)

Comment: You're setting the x and y positions of the circle to (10,10), and that's right over the text. Where do you expect the circle to show up?

Comment: The shape should appear behind the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`selection.append()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append) will append the circle as the last child of its parent `<g>` element. Because SVGs elements are rendered in document order, this will cover the text which is located before the newly appended circle. You can use [`selection.insert("circle", ":first-child")`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert) to insert the circle before the first element in the group, and, hence, before the text element.

```js
// New User Data
var myData = [{
  text:'A',
  shape:'circle',
  x:10,
  y:10
}];

// Remove existing shape and replace with a new shape
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var g = svg.select('g');
var sh = g.select('.shape');
sh.remove();
var newsh = g.selectAll('.shape').data(myData);
newsh.enter().insert('circle', ':first-child').attr({
  "cx": function(d){ return d.x;},
  "cy": function(d){ return d.y;},
  "r":10
})
.classed('shape circle',true);
```

```css
text {
 fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<svg>
<g>
  <rect x='0' y='0' height='20' width='20' class='shape rect'/>
  <text x='10' y='10' text-anchor='middle' alignment-baseline='middle'>A</text>
</g>
</svg>
```